# Pass array as parameter python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to pass all the arrays such as molecularWeight(concentration,time)
`

```
concentration_time = np.array([[0,83],
                               [0.04,89],
                               [0.06,95],
                               [0.08,104],
                               [0.1,114],
                               [0.12,126],
                               [0.14,139],
                               [0.16,155],
                               [0.20,191]])


concentration = [item[0] for item in concentration_time]
time = [item[1] for item in concentration_time]


t0 = 83

def molecularWeight(c,t):
    answer = ((t/t0)-1)/c
    return answer

molecularWeight(concentration,time)
```

I was expecting to get an output with 9 different outputs. I want to pass all pairs for c and t and get an output for each.

I get the desired output when I manually pass the values:`molecularWeight(0.04,89.0)`
but not when I try to pass all of them using the previously defined variables: `molecularWeight(concentration,time)` ERROR:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: As well as the code you need to fix the data as you will get a divide by zero error for the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Lists in python do not support addition/subtraction/other mathematical operations.
You need to either use `numpy`, or explicitly do the operations within a list-comprehension (or loop) over the `zipped` element pairs...

For instance:

```
import numpy as np

def molecularWeight(c,t):
    c = np.array(c)
    t = np.array(t)
    answer = ((t/t0)-1)/c
    return answer

molecularWeight(concentration,time)
```

or conversely:

```
def molecularWeight(c,t):
    try:
        answer = ((t/t0)-1)/c
    except TypeError:
        answer = [((t_/t0)-1)/c_ for c_, t_ in zip(c, t)]
    return answer

molecularWeight(concentration,time)
```

Note that you started off with a `numpy` array, so you could just stick to that from the start, leave the function as you defined it, but make sure to pass in numpy-arrays and not lists:

```
concentration = concentration_time[:, 0]
time = concentration_time[:, 1]
```

Comment: I think you're overthinking what OP wants

Comment: I think I understood exactly what he wants, and I'm givving him the tools to do things better next time, and not just a copy-paste solution for this time.

Answer (score 0):

add safety for your division (1e-9) here for example to avoid div to zero

```
concentration ,time = concentration_time[:,0], concentration_time[:,1]
t0 = 83
def molecularWeight(c,t):
    return ((t / t0) - 1) / (c + 1e-9)

molecularWeight(concentration,time)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably what you want, if I'm understanding correctly.

You are correctly giving the list to the function as an input, but not iterating over it correctly.

```py
def molecularWeight(inputs):
    answers = []

    for c, t in inputs: 
        answer = ((t/t0)-1)/c
        answers.append(answer)

    return answers
```